# Dynamic programming - task scheduling

Tags: dynamic, task, scheduling, lazy-evaluation

This is a question nobody was able to answer correctly to at a "flash test" in my class in my college:

**We are given:**

int N < 1000 slots of time

int[] C:  -10 000 <= C[i] <= 10 000  payment corresponding to each of the slots

int T: number of slots we have to use

**The problem is stated in the following way:**

A lazy worker has N slots of time in a total workday.

For each slot of time he gets a certain payment (C[i] - which, unrealistically, can also be negative).

He wants to choose intervals of exactly T slots so that he will get the biggest payment. We have to choose the intervals he will work in. For example [1, 4] - from the first slot to the 4th.

The problem is that every time he takes a break, when he comes back to work, the first slot he works will not be paid, because he is getting used to work again, just like a lazy person. Therefore, we can also choose empty intervals like [5, 5], this could come in handy if we have negative payments. These will get the payment 0, regardless of what payment is associated to the slot beforehand.

**To make it clearer, I'm going to give a simple example:**

Let's say we have N=5 slots, and we want to choose T=4. C={3, 9, 1, 1, 7}

The best solution is the intervals [1, 2]; [4, 5] with a total payment of 9+7=16

We cover a total of T=4 slots, the solution is valid.

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt at the problem, there may be something faster though. Let f(i, j, t) denote the best way to fit t spots inside the subarray N[i, j] (inclusive of i and j), such that N[i] is covered and N[j] is covered. Now note that f(i, j, t) = max { f(i, j-1, t-1) + C[j], max_{1 < k < j - i} f(i, j-k, t-1) }. The base cases are f(i, j, t) = 0 if (j - i + 1 < t), f(i, i, 1) = 0, f(i, j, 1) = inf, and f(i, j, 2) = C[i] + C[j]. The complexity I believe is O(N^3 * T), in that the table f has size N^2 * T, and inside f we need to take max of (k < j - i) to get the additional factor of N in our complexity. Thus O(N^3 * T). Hopefully I haven't overlooked something in the problem.

In order to find the solution from the table f, just do max_{i,j} f(i, j, T).